# Automatic video conversion on upload?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, video, conversion

I want to have a page for users that can be used to upload videos in multiple formats and after upload, SharePoint can convert it into a standard format like `.avi`, `.mp4` etc. which I will then display on the SharePoint website.

Can anyone recommend a robust way to do this ?

I have tried to use ffmpeg and made a prototype C# application with an ffmpeg wrapper that will convert the video for me. But this involves invoking another process for ffmpeg and waiting for it. This seems very fragile as it hangs sometimes when ffmpeg does not return.

I tried to Google for something like this but couldn't find any thing even close to what I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

.avi is anything but 'a standard' format for SharePoint. It will not play in the HTML5 video player. Stick to the mp4.

I would have done it the following way:
Create an Asset Library and attach an event receiver to it. Implement the ItemAdded method, which is asynchronous (i.e. it can take as much time as it needs). In that method, do the actual conversion, which results in a new file which you will create in that library (make sure you don't fire it's events, when creating, otherwise you may end up with an endless loop). At the end of the conversion you may delete the original file, if you want to.